# Can't plot Zipf's law in R

Tags: r, distribution, tm, qdap

I have a big list of terms and their frequency loaded from a text file and I converted it to a table:

```
myTbl = read.table("word_count.txt")  # read text file 

colnames(myTbl)<-c("term", "frequency")
head(myTbl, n = 10)

> head(myTbl, n = 10)
    term frequency
1     de     35945
2      i     34850
3  \xe3n     19936
4      s     15348
5     cu     13722
6     la     13505
7     se     13364
8     pe     13361
9     nu     12693
10     o     11995
```

I should probably add a column with word rank and then plot rank against frequency, but how do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than roll your own calculation, it would be easier to use the `tm` package.  Convert myTbl to a term document matrix (tdm)

```
library(tm)
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(myTbl) # there are many more clean up steps, but I am simplifying
```

Then you you have not just Zipf but also Heaps and plots to display.

```
Zipf_plot(tdm) 
Heaps_plot(tdm) # how vocabulary grows as size of text grows
```

Alternatively, you can use the `qdap` package and its rank frequency plots.  Here is a quote from the vignette:

> Rank Frequency Plots are a way of visualizing word rank versus
>   frequencies as related to Zipf's law which states that the rank of a
>   word is inversely related to its frequency. The rank_freq_mplot and
>   rank_freq_plot provide the means to plot the ranks and frequencies of
>   words (with rank_freq_mplot plotting by grouping variable(s)).
>   Rank_freq_mplot utilizes the ggplot2 package, whereas, rank_freq_plot
>   employs base graphics.